# How to change chart.js chart's grid color?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Basically, I want to change grid color of my chart.js chart.
Here is my code:

```
const options = {
        scales: {
            x: {
            grid: {
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)',
                borderColor: 'red'
            }
            },
            y: {
            grid: {
                color: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.1)',
                borderColor: 'green'
            }
            }
        }
        };


var chart0 = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart0"), {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
       labels: [some,lables,here],
       datasets: [
       { 
       data: dataarr0,
       fill: true,
       backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
       }
       ],
       options: options
       }
   });
```

Chart just didn't seem to care and stays the same color. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `options` have to be defined on the same level as the `type` and `data` are defined. Then it works fine:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          color: 'red',
          borderColor: 'green'
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          color: 'red',
          borderColor: 'green'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```